# ElasticSearch, matching via large array values

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

Version: v7.6.0

My app is similar to Tinder in that it shows users people they have swiped on.

The user can swipe an unlimited amount of users. Potentially people could have 100k+ UID's they swiped on.

I use a query like so (the **20k is 20k more 'match' objects**)

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [{"match":{"uid":"876123c4-7b63-4a90-843b-a0c61f175524"}},{"match":{"uid":"a5db9040-0704-49d8-95b5-7441263a6c5c"}},+20,534
    }
  }
}
```

This works, the problem is it's a little slow (14 seconds+).

How else could I do a query like this?

Comment: Please provide information like which ES version, how many shards and replicas, indices on your cluster and is it always 15 sec or during load on cluster, try to provide as much as information relevant to troubleshoot perf issue

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it's more of an architectural question. The power of the machines doesn't matter. Using version. v7.6.0

Comment: did you consider using the filters rather than query? filters are cached and look like you can use filters in your use-case.

Comment: @OpsterESNinja I looked for an example and could not find one where you could use a large array of uids to filter results.